# Find the max value in nested array MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with nested arrays as below:

```
[
   {
      "title":"Foo",
      "arr":[
         [
            {
               "value":"2021-11-13T00:00:00.000Z",
               "baz":10
            },
            {
               "value":"2021-11-12T00:00:00.000Z",
               "baz":0
            }
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Bar",
      "arr":[
         [
            {
               "value":"2021-12-03T00:00:00.000Z",
               "baz":10
            },
            {
               "value":"2021-12-07T00:00:00.000Z",
               "baz":0
            }
         ]
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to filter out the largest value (i.e., latest date) for each document such that the result is:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Foo",
        "value": "2021-11-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
    {
        "title": "Bar",
        "value": "2021-12-07T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
]
```

How can this query be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query1

- find the local max in the iner arrays
- find the global max in the outer arrays

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70297034-1)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"value": 
     {"$max": {"$map": {"input": "$arr", "in": {"$max": "$$this.value"}}}}}},
 {"$unset": ["_id", "arr"]}])
```

Query2

- this flattens the array to not be nested, and takes the max after
- `reduce` and `concatArrays` to make the nested array one not nested array
- take the `max` for each array
- project to keep only those 2 fields like expected output

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70297034)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
    {"arr": 
      {"$reduce": 
        {"input": "$arr",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}},
  {"$set": {"value": {"$max": "$arr.value"}}},
  {"$project": {"_id": 0, "title": 1, "value": 1}}])
```

Comment: Good example of the "$reduce with an initialValue of empty *array* and using concatArrays" pattern.   Very powerful.

Comment: i use Clojure, so those are common things, but in MongoDB `concatArrays` is slow, for example you cant do this for arrays of 1k+ members, like use 1k `concatArrays`  inside a reduce ,it will be slow if collection is big. Test it your self sometime, i did benchmarks in the past, but for not very big arrays works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$reduce` you can also use `$filter` and `$map`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         arr: {
            $map: {
               input: "$arr",
               as: "item",
               in: {
                  $filter: {
                     input: "$$item",
                     cond: { $eq: ["$$this.baz", { $max: "$$item.baz" }] }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

It is not clear why you have an array `arr` with just one element. If your collection has always just one element element in `arr`, then you can also bypass the `$map`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         arr: {
            $let: {
               vars: { item: { $first: "$arr" } },
               in: {
                  $filter: {
                     input: "$$item",
                     cond: { $eq: ["$$this.value", { $max: "$$item.value" }] }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```